# python realtime database. 'Invalid path: Path specified exceeds the maximum length that can be written (768 bytes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to sign in using my localId and idToken but this error throws up
im printing the error that firebase return it to me.

```
   main.py
    try:
        with open("refresh_token.txt", "r") as f:
            refresh_token = f.read()

        #use refresh token to remember the user Id when signing
        id_token, local_id = self.my_firebase.exchange_refresh_token(refresh_token)

        # Get database data
        result = requests.get("https://fitness-tutorial-android.firebaseio.com/" + local_id + ".json?auth=" + id_token)
        print("Is result, Ok?", result.ok)
        data = json.loads(result.content.decode())
        print(data)

    except Exception as e:
        print("check", e)
        pass


myfirebase.py
def exchange_refresh_token(self, refresh_token):
    request_ref = "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key={0}".format(self.wak)
    data = '{"grantType": "refresh_token", "refreshToken": "%s"}' %refresh_token
    request_object = requests.post(request_ref, data=data)
    print("Refresh OK ?", request_object.ok)
    print(json.loads(request_object.content.decode()))
    request_object_json = request_object.json()
    local_id = request_object_json['user_id']
    id_token = request_object_json['id_token']
    return local_id, id_token
```

and this is the printed error

Refresh OK ? True

Is result, Ok? False

{'error': 'Invalid path: Path specified exceeds the maximum length that can be written (768 bytes).'}

check 'avatar'

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What is the full path of the location that you're trying to write?

Comment: @DougStevenson im trying to connect to realtime database so the user can change their profile but cannot change his/her friends profile, im trying to get access to this url ("https://fitness-tutorial-android.firebaseio.com/" + local_id + ".json?auth=" + id_token)

Comment: That's not a full path, that's a string composition. What is the actual string there, after all the string concatenations are done?

Comment: @DougStevenson i will split the id_token in 2 parts because the comment character limit is not enough id_token = id_token_1 + id_token_2

Comment: @DougStevenson : 'id_token_1' : eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ2YjgzOTdjOGU0NmE3M2ZiMDExMDk2YjUyMDE1YTZlNjZkMDMyZWIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vZml0bmVzcy10dXRvcmlhbC1hbmRyb2lkIiwiYXVkIjoiZml0bmVzcy10dXRvcmlhbC1hbmRyb2lkIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTYzODU0NDg0LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNHRMVnJnMjlhWlZQTHVYTHduVGtKdGVDeHgxMyIsInN1YiI6IjR0TFZyZzI5YVpWUEx1WEx3blRrSnRlQ3h4MTMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjM5NTI0MjcsImV4cCI6MTU2Mzk1NjAyNywiZW1haWwiOiJnb2dvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJnb2dvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdfSwi

Comment: What's the solution here?